# Spam emails from Suse server: test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp

Tags: linux, cron, sendmail, opensuse

Have a virtual server with old Suse. About a month ago cron started spamming me with emails like this:

```
Subject: test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
Body:/usr/share/sendmail/sendmail: 899: /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail-msp: not found
```

I use postfix (sendmail was deleted long time ago) and can't see how to turn off this spamming email. And yes, no one change anything on the server (neither install updates, nor reconfigure it). At one day this email spam just started. And I can't find any cron tasks that send this emails.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have not removed **fully** **all** sendmail packages.